# Strains when one vertex of a 2 dimensional square element is pulled up

Tags: stress-strain, solid-mechanics

ABCD is a square and C is pulled up by a small amount(say x) keeping other vertices else fixed, what are the strains in the element.

I assumed it would be same as pulling CD up by x/2 and then shearing the side BC up by remaining x/2(resulting in ε<sub>yy</sub> and ε<sub>xy</sub>) but that requires B to move up too and that is not the case. I'm a little confused here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical tensile strain will be maximum on BC side as BC/ (BC+x). And from there to the left it will decrease as the radials of tension stress lines from C to corresponding points on the base will get longer and also stress projection to vertical which is cos(theta) smaller, therefore less tensile strain but increasing slowly shear strain.

On the triangle ADC there will be predominantly vertical shear strain because the magnitude of  tensile stress is minimal but shear is increasing.

And there will be a bit of necking narrowing the middle horizontal part due to the Poisson effect.